# Error when using Firebase CLI in Cloud Build

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-build, firebase-cli

I get the following error when I run "cloud-build-local --dryrun=false ." on my local machine:

> Firebase Management API has not been used in project 32555940559
> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebase.googleapis.com/overview?project=32555940559
> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
> the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

The project number listed is not the number of any of my projects. I Googled this number and it seems like more users get errors with this project number in it. I already checked the following:

- The account that I am signed in with has owner permissions for the project
- "gcloud config list" show that the correct project and account are active
- The project is listed in my .firebase.rc file

Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: I am using Firebase CLI version 8.7.0 which is the latest version at this moment.

Comment: "gcloud builds submit ." does work but "cloud-build-local --dryrun=false ." does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cloud-build-local is the command used to [build a image locally](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-debug-locally).

The Cloud Build local environment, as well as all other GCP local environments, are outside of your Google Cloud environment, hence the project-id you are seeing here references the gcloud project number. This means that gcloud will unable to use the login credentials for your respective project and will not automatically authenticate with the Cloud Build service account needed for the Cloud Build gcloud commands.

In this case you would need to utilize [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login). This will provide new user credentials for use with [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) so as to authorize you to utilize the needed service accounts for local Cloud Build development.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I still dont fully understand why I am not able to run cloud-build-local for the project using my own account that has project owner rights. For other projects this works just fine. I tried to use the command you specified. But in the end I got it working by using the command under method 1 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56826028) answer.