# Authenticating Pulumi to manage firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

When tryin to create firebase resources using pulumi I get following error:

> error: 1 error occurred:
>
> - Error creating Project: googleapi: Error 403: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the firebase.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

As far as I understand this, the only way to use Pulumi with a Firebase project is to use the service account (with proper access) and it is not possible to use the `gloud ...` way to authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

Is not pulumi is how you are authenticating against `gcloud`. It could be you are authenticated with an end-user account and not a service account

Please check the following documentation.
[Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK which are not supported by the translate.googleapis.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823383/your-application-has-authenticated-using-end-user-credentials-from-the-google-cl)

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing

https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/installation-configuration/