# How to resolve the error of Google Speech-To-Text Error?

Tags: node.js, gcloud

I have setted package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/My Path/my.json && node app.js"
},
```

but, I have a Error like this,

```
(node:28590) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the speech.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/. If you are getting this error with curl or similar tools, you may need to specify 'X-Goog-User-Project' HTTP header for quota and billing purposes. For more information regarding 'X-Goog-User-Project' header, please check https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters.
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/bruce/Workspace/amosense/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/bruce/Workspace/amosense/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/bruce/Workspace/amosense/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/bruce/Workspace/amosense/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
at /Users/bruce/Workspace/amosense/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:28590) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:28590) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've tried following the guide below, but I'm still getting the same error as above.
[similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823383/your-application-has-authenticated-using-end-user-credentials-from-the-google-cl/56826028)

Strangely, it works fine on the server, but keeps getting an error on localhost. I hope someone can guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the same operating systems on server and local machine?

Comment: @vitooh server is google cloud, my local machine is macos.

Comment: I have seen this issue already, but I cannot find an example. Can you post some example code? What do you mean "server is google cloud"? is it vm? app engine? anything else?

Comment: @vitooh Thank you for your concern. 'google cloud is app engine(e.g google STT)

Comment: I am not able to replicate the issue, but I do not have macos available. Are you able to create some minimal example? code and `package,json`?